# delete and replace strings matching pattern in xml file

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Team,
I have an xml file that needs to be modified for a personal hack project. Need help how can I club all this in fewer operations.

all below works on my mac but I need to see if I can club them into one line command. example for similar operations is there an OR operation I can do in sed syntax?
something like sed `sed -i '' '/classes|lines>|package|source|<source/d' coverage.xml`

secondly, an answer below suggests to use xmlstarlet
`xmlstarlet edit -d '//package' coverage.xml` with this approach it is deleting the entire block where I just want to delete the line not the block because am formatting it. see how i am renaming class to file and then making that class as parent node.!

```
sed -i '' '/classes/d' coverage.xml
sed -i '' '/lines>/d' coverage.xml
sed -i '' '/<method/d' coverage.xml
sed -i '' '/package/d' coverage.xml
sed -i '' '/source/d' coverage.xml
sed -i '' '/<source/d' coverage.xml
```

replace

```
sed -i '' 's/class/file/g' coverage.xml
```

replace at line having `<coverage`

```
sed -i '' '/<coverage/s/version="2.0.3"/version="1"/g' coverage.xml
```

sample output to be converted. Note this output is being sent to sonarqube server that does not accept this format. so I am manually modifying it to send what sonarqube accepts and it works fine. but here in this question my ask is about how I can achieve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage
SYSTEM 'http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd'>
<coverage branch-rate="0.0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.5936254980079682" lines-covered="447" lines-valid="753" timestamp="1672197709" version="2.0.3">
    <packages>
        <package line-rate="0.7614678899082569" branch-rate="0.0" name="src.services.secrets.keys" complexity="0">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" filename="src/services/guava/keys/keys.go" line-rate="0.7614678899082569" name="src.services.guava.keys.keys.go">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line branch="false" hits="0" number="109"/>
                        <line branch="false" hits="0" number="123"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </package>
        <package line-rate="0.5944055944055944" branch-rate="0.0" name="src.services.guava.vault" complexity="0">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" filename="src/services/secrets/vault/vault.go" line-rate="0.5944055944055944" name="src.services.guava.vault.vault.go">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line branch="false" hits="1" number="251"/>
                        <line branch="false" hits="1" number="253"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </package>
    </packages>
</coverage>
```

expected output below that works with sonarqube

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage
  SYSTEM 'http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd'>
<coverage branch-rate="0.0" branches-covered="true" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" lineToCover-rate="0.5936254980079682" lineToCovers-covered="447" lineToCovers-valid="753" timestamp="1672173715" version="1">
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/guava/keys/keys.go" lineToCover-rate="0.7614678899082569" name="src.services.guava.keys.keys.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="16"/>
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="17"/>
        </file>
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/guava/server/server.go" lineToCover-rate="0.744" name="src.services.guava.server.server.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="153"/>
        </file>
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/secrets/tools/keyrotate/cmd_get.go" lineToCover-rate="0.0" name="src.services.guava.tools.keyrotate.cmd_get.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="true" lineNumber="16"/>
        </file>
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/secrets/tools/keyrotate/cmd_rotate.go" lineToCover-rate="0.72" name="src.services.guava.tools.keyrotate.cmd_rotate.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="75"/>
        </file>
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/secrets/tools/keyrotate/main.go" lineToCover-rate="0.0" name="src.services.guava.tools.keyrotate.main.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="true" lineNumber="80"/>
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="true" lineNumber="81"/>
        </file>
        <file branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0" path="src/services/guava/vault/vault.go" lineToCover-rate="0.5944055944055944" name="src.services.guava.vault.vault.go">
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="251"/>
                <lineToCover branch="false" covered="false" lineNumber="253"/>
        </file>
</coverage>
```

Comment: You're getting downvoted for a few reasons. Firstly, using sed probably isn't a good idea ([see the famous answer about using regex to parse XML, which also applies to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5774952), and [the meta post about that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant)). Using a parser in your preferred language (not shell) would be much less brittle. Secondly, you can combine commands with `&&`, but your question doesn't make it clear _why_ you need them in one command, or if that's suitable for you.

Comment: Don't parse xml with shell. Use a utility that can do xml validation on the changes like `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: the problem is xml that is generated is not according to the server standard so when I am submitting it I have to make these changes to get it accepted. so how does xmlstarlet gonna help?

Comment: @ZacAnger I seriously don't understand what that post you referred to is implying. all i see 3k votes and stuff and not answering my question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

To edit an `XML` file, you have special tool like `xmlstarlet` that let you edit the `XML` as well. Please, forget using `sed` and `regex` to parse `XML`. Better use a real `XML` parser and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

### To move nodes

```
xmlstarlet ed --move '/path/to/node//childs' '/another/path' file.xml
```

### To delete a node:

```
xmlstarlet edit -d '//node' file.xml
```

### To edit a node and @version attribut:

```
 xmlstarlet ed -Lu '/coverage/@version' -v '1' file.xml
```

will update the version with good practices.

The `-L` is the same as `sed -i ''`: *edit in-place*

### To install on Mac:

```
brew install xmlstarlet
```

Comment: thanks but when i delete the node `<package` it is deleting the entire block inbetween which I want to keep and not delete. I literally just want to delete lines and make the `<class` as `<file`. how can i achieve this with xmlstarlet?

Comment: If you delete `/coverage`, you remove all. `XML` is a tree, if you cut it, nothing remains. If you cut a branch, then an example is `//line/lineToCover` to remove all `lineToCover` nodes

Comment: There's is no _line_ in `XML`, there's nodes, attributes... You example is not _minimal_  as  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **TL;DR**

Comment: so then in that case, am set to use SED correct? because my goal is to make that `class` field as parent node and rename it as `file` . that is why i posted output before and after operation.

Comment: Do you read the doc ? Simply: `xmlstarlet ed --move '/path/to/node//childs' '/another/path' file 

`

Answer (score -1):

I hope, it works for your solution,

```
import re
with open('./stackoverflow_xml_replace.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if '<coverage' in lines[index]:
            lines[index] = lines[index].replace('version="2.0.3"', 'version="1"')
        if 'class' in lines[index]:
            lines[index] = re.sub(r"\bclass\b","file",lines[index])
        if 'filename' in lines[index]:
            lines[index] = re.sub(r"\bfilename\b","path",lines[index])
        if '<line' in lines[index]:
            lines[index] = lines[index].replace('line', 'lineToCover')
        if 'number' in lines[index]:
            lines[index] = re.sub(r"\bnumber\b","lineNumber",lines[index])
        if '<source' in lines[index]:
            lines.remove(lines[index])
with open('./stackoverflow_xml_replace_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
print(lines)
```

Comment: Use a Python `XML` module like `lxml`

Comment: Oky, I will try